# Opera Push Notification - Unable to trigger notificationclick event

Tags: push-notification, opera, chromium, service-worker

I am facing an issue with Opera Desktop Browser 47 when trying to send push notifications.

While the notifications are getting delivered correctly, I am unable to trigger the 'notificationclick' event. Nothing in the console as well.

**Service Worker: (SW snippet with sample test data)**

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {

event.waitUntil(self.registration.pushManager.getSubscription().then(function(o) {
        if (event.data) {
            console.log(event.data);
            var json=event.data.json();
            var notifs = [];
            const title = 'Sample Opera Title';
            const options = {
                body: 'Body of push notification',
            };
            payload_notifs.push(self.registration.showNotification(title, options));

            return Promise.all(notifs);
        }
    }));
});

self.onnotificationclick = function(event) {
    console.log('On notification click: ', event.notification.tag);
    event.notification.close();
};
```

Now, the thing is when I am putting a breakpoint just after sending the notification (Not letting the event complete), the notification is getting delivered, the 'notificationclick' event is also working.

This is actually very strange because things are working fine on other browsers with the same service code.

Does any one have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {

event.waitUntil(self.registration.pushManager.getSubscription().then(function(o) {
        if (event.data) {
            console.log(event.data);
            var json=event.data.json();
            var notifs = [];
            const title = 'Sample Opera Title';
            const options = {
                body: 'Body of push notification',
            };
            payload_notifs.push(self.registration.showNotification(title, options));

            Promise.all(notifs);
        }
    }));
});

self.onnotificationclick = function(event) {
    console.log('On notification click: ', event.notification.tag);
    event.notification.close();
};
```

Remove `return`, Opera is doing something weirdly.